# Is it possible to upgrade a database created with openorCreatedatabase sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oncreate

Any idea how to update a sqlite database created with openorcreatedatabase. The problem is that already published in market the app.  And to the new version of the app is added fields to the database.

I tried this way

```
package com.example.database1;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ManagerDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String dropTablaUser = "drop table if exists user;";
private static final String createTablaUser = "create table if not exists user(userid integer primary key);";
    public ManagerDB(Context contexto, String namedb, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(contexto, namedb, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {

            db.execSQL(createTablaUser);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error to open or create the database" + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionafter,
            int newversion) {
        try {
             db.execSQL(dropTablaUser);            
             db.execSQL(createTablaUser);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error to open or create the database" + e);
        }

    }

}
```

But those who have the older version will not update the database because it was not created in this way but with openorcreatedatabase

Comment: Some comments about the code you posted: Catching exceptions in sqlite helper callbacks is a bad idea (the helper thinks everything is ok when it's not), and creating and then dropping the table (in `onUpgrade()`) is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For this upgrade, you have to do the version check and update mechanism by hand.

(This is easiest if the old database and the SQLiteOpenHelper database have different names.)

In the `onCreate` function, check if some old database file exists.
If it does exist, open it (or better, [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) it), and copy the data into the new database.

Comment: Thanks for the info and an idea of ​​how to do it with code. Might you help me?